# Block another user from accessing the Rails application with my authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, authorization, login-control

I have hosted a rails application, an online examination system. The users need to get registered to get access to the system. So each user will be provided with a unique combination of credentials. Let us assume my `user-name/password` is `demo/demo123`. I want my app to block another person logging in to the system even if he knows my credentials. Any solution for such scenario.

Thanks for any help :)-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Cookie would be a better solution. When the user gets registered create a Cookie value specific to the User and System and in encrypted format (for security reason) and save it in the database corresponding to that user. Check for this Cookie token while logging in. When the user clears the cookie, s(he) can request the Administrator to clear out the DB cookie for creating a new one.

Using IP will not be a better solution since in a network, there can be dynamic IP's allocated to the PC's.

Comment: But the fact that IPs will be assigned dynamically doesn't mean its not secure, since a unique IP will be assigned to each machine via the DHCP server. And if you are trying to prevent one person from collaborating with another person on an exam, couldn't they potentially read their browser cookie and send it to someone else? That seems like a potential security hole, whereas an IP is harder to fake.

Answer (score 1):

You could record the user's IP address in the database when they first log in, and only allow logging in using the same credentials but from a *new* IP address after some waiting period of, say, 1 hour, or until the current examination is complete. That should prevent more than one user being logged in to the same user account within a short time period.

The user's IP address can be accessed in a Rails controller using `request.remote_ip`.

Comment: Wouldn't this cause other difficulties when using a dynamic ip? you could however check if the user is already signed in or add an extra passphrase to the login fields.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [lock](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/lock) gem to add a password to the entire application.

First, add to your Gemfile.

```
gem 'lock'
```

Then

```
bundle install
```

Next, create your password

```
rails g lock:create_password_file yourpasswordhere
```

Finally, add lock your application controller, or whatever you'd like (see [documentation](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/lock)).

```
ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  lock
end
```

Comment: Kindly understand the question and then answer it.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand @Rajesh. It does "block another person logging in to the system even if he knows my credentials."

Comment: I don't want to lock my application. I want to block another person logging in with my credentials. So, others would be able to login in to the app iff they have their own credentials. Hope you got the idea.